# Getting RVM to read an rbenv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

I've tried googling but can only find information on transitioning from rvm to rbenv entirely.

I've always used rvm and like it however a lot of the projects I work with have a .ruby-version file for rbenv rather than a .rvmrc file.

Is there any way I can get rvm to read the version from the .ruby-version file? All I do at the moment is open up .ruby-version, take the exact string that's there, and then run 'rvm use string'. So if it's 2.1.2, 'rvm use 2.1.2'

Is there an easy way to automate this? I'm assuming rvm has to have a feature to allow it to read rbenv files but I haven't found it yet...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should already work? [If a .rvmrc file is not present, then RVM should attempt to read from a `.ruby-version` file](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#supported-files). Perhaps you have both files in the folder, causing a conflict? Perhaps you've got some custom config in RVM that disables this behaviour? Perhaps you're running a (very) old RVM version that doesn't support this behaviour?

Comment: *"only `.rvmrc` will work in all RVM versions; the other files were introduced in RVM `1.11.0`"*, but that version was released way back in December 2011!

Comment: You could also consider specifying the ruby version in the `Gemfile`, as this will ensure that anyone running the project "must" use the correct ruby version, regardless of how ruby is installed on the machine.

Comment: Thanks for the research - I assumed that feature wasn't present as it wasn't working for me out the box - I'm running 1.29 so as you say it must be a config option I've assigned manually - thanks again